# Java (with Mule and/or Spring) vs .NET for SOA development

Tags: java, .net, jakarta-ee, soa, mule

There are several posts on stackoverflow regarding Java vs. .NET, however, I feel that there needs to be more explanation with regards to each technology as applied to SOA development.

I am very new to SOA development, and of course, I have a lot of questions.  It appears that everything .NET can do can be accomplished in Java, and vice versa.  However, Java has a lot of other frameworks, such as Mule and Spring that can add some additional functionality in the SOA world.  However, not having worked with those frameworks, I am unsure of what type of advantage they can provide (if any).

EDIT: Made the questions more objective (I had to remove questions soliciting for a comparison between .NET and Java):

The areas that I would like specifically clarified are:

1. What features does Mule and Spring add to the Java J2EE framework that are not provided in .NET?
2. Does Mule and Spring add security tools and API's that provide equivalent features to .NET?
3. Does Mule and Spring make Java J2EE more effective for REST and SOAP messaging capabilities?
4. Does Mule and Spring increase J2EE's robustness for SOA?
5. Does Mule and Spring make J2EE easier to develop?

I would appreciate feedback from developers who have experienced .NET and Java technologies.

Thank You

**EDIT**: I realized that I don't actually need Mule for SOA development.  Mule is just if you need an ESB.

Comment: I really don't understand why my question was closed as not constructive, when there are many other similarly asked questions on SO.  I will try to rephrase, but ultimately, this is a good question that needs to be asked, and I would prefer for industry experts to answer it.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more objective.  Can it be re-opened?

Comment: While question is closed, I've got answer to your 5th question: Spring *was* made to make J2EE easier to develop.

Comment: Mule doesn't build on J2EE nor extend it. It's an integration broker and framework. Without taking much risk, I can say that you can cover all the technical needs of your SOA endeavor with .NET or Java. IMO you won't be able to decide between the two if your criteria list doesn't include license, tooling and hosting costs.